# List of subsets of which their elements add up to n using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, subset-sum

I'm writing this function which I want to print all the sublists of a given list with integers. The sum of these integers should be equal to a given number `n`. There is also a help variable `i` which starts with value 0. Both the list and each sublist are an `ArrayList`. So the method looks like this right now:

```
public static void printSublists(ArrayList numbers, ArrayList sublist, int n,
            int i) {

        if (sublist.sum() == n) {
            System.out.println(sublist.toString());
        } 
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
                sublist.add(numbers.get(i));
                printSublists(numbers, sublist, n, i + 1);
                sublist.remove(numbers.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course I already have the method `sum()`. The method does this now:
Lets say `numbers = [1, 3 , 4]` and `n == 4`, then the method should print `[4]` and `[1 ,3]`, but it only prints `[1, 3]` ? I think the for-loop has to do the trick right? I would appreciate it if someone puts me on the right track.

**update: 
the values I'm giving to the method:**

```
numbers = [1, 3, 4]
n = 4
i = 0
sublist = []
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I forgot to say that I want it to be recursive :)

Comment: This page has a generic algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: This has to be the worst page on Wikipedia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion stops when you see the first sublist with a sum of `n`. The problem is not (only) the loop but the exit criteria. <strike>Your recursive function should stop when the sublist length is 0.</strike>

---

Here I just wrote a working, recursive solution for your problem. It is different  but I wasn't able to fix yours. While you start with an empty sublist, I chose to init the recursion with the full list an divide it into smaller sublists. This creates a tree like structure:

```
                        [1234]
                     [123]  [234]
                   [12] [23]   [34]
                  [1][2]  [3]    [4]
```

We see immediately, that we have to walk down "right" until we reach the first leaf (`1`), then we only walk "left". This way we visit all sublists only once.

Here's the idea written in Java:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(1);
  list.add(3);
  list.add(4);
  list.add(0);
  printSublists(list, list, 4, true, 0);
}

public static void printSublists(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> sublist, int n, boolean walkRight, int level) {

  // the test
  if (sum(sublist) == n)
     System.out.println(sublist);

  // the exit criteia (leaf reached)
  if (sublist.size() == 1)
     return;

  // visit the right sublist
  if (walkRight) 
    printSublists(numbers, sublist.subList(0, sublist.size()-1), n, walkRight, level+1);

  // we only walk the right path once
  walkRight = false;

  // visit the left sublist
  printSublists(numbers, sublist.subList(1, sublist.size()), n, walkRight, level+1);
}
```

And that's the output:

```
[1, 3]
[4]
[4, 0]
```

Comment: I don't understand how in this way the length of the sublist becomes 0? It has to stop (each time = nr of possible subsets) when the sum of numbers is n. Right?

Comment: There's much more wrong with your code then just the stop criteria. The wrong exit criteria hides some more issues and it doesn't even compile (`ArrayList` does not have a `sum()` method).

Answer (score 2):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    printSublists(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 1, 2)), new HashSet<Integer>(), 4);
}

private void printSublists(Set<Integer> numbers, Set<Integer> subList, int expected) {

    for (Integer element : numbers) {
        subList.add(element);
        if (sum(subList) == expected) {
            System.out.println("result =" + subList);
        }
        Set<Integer> listWithoutElement = withoutElement(numbers, element);
        printSublists(listWithoutElement, subList, expected);
        subList.remove(element);

    }
}

private Set<Integer> withoutElement(Set<Integer> numbers, Integer element) {
    Set<Integer> newList = new HashSet<Integer>(numbers);
    newList.remove(element);
    return newList;
}

private int sum(Collection<Integer> sublist) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer e : sublist) {
        sum += e;
    }
    return sum;

}
```

Here is your solution. This problem should be for sets, not for list.

If you have set **[2,3,4,1,2]** the solution should be **[3,1] [4] [2,2]**. Then the problem has to be recursive. You have to remove duplication of course :)

Comment: Forgot to say that I want it to be recursive. Updated my question.

Comment: BTW, this seems exactly copied from some other website. Unless you're the owner of that page.

Comment: The code is written by me.  Algorithm is so easy so I think you find similar solutions.

Comment: I rewrote according to wikipedia. The problem is for sets. You have to remove duplication for performance. Code is mine :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code's for loop:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
            sublist.add(numbers.get(i));
            printSublists(numbers, sublist, n, i + 1);
            sublist.remove(numbers.get(i));
        }
```

The variable `j` is never used.  So you're doing exactly the same thing repeatedly, which I seriously doubt is what you want to do.

Comment: I guess in my case the for-loop should run twice right? The number of sublist? Thanks btw, will look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

probably u will need to do something this way -

```
public static void printSublists(ArrayList numbers, ArrayList sublist, int n,
        int i) {

    if (sublist.sum() == n) {
        System.out.println(sublist.toString());
        sublist.removeAll(sublist);//added remove all here
    } 
    else {
        //for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {//commented this line
        while(i<number.size()){//need while loop
            sublist.add(numbers.get(i));
            printSublists(numbers, sublist, n, ++i);//i+1 changed to ++i
            //sublist.remove(numbers.get(i));// commented here
        }
    }
}
```